# Changing My Site and My Profile tab text

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, mysite

How do I go about changing the My Site and My Profile text on everyone's My Site within SharePoint 2007?

I can't seem to find anywhere where these are set in any of the master pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem rather than create my own My Site Host as was suggested on another forum I used jQuery to find the tabs and change their name on the fly. Not the greatest fix but it works flawlessly

Comment: But did this work for adding tabs and tabs content? you can but doesnt seem like a good fix to interact with custom properties.

Answer (score 0):

**12\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\SPSPERS\default.aspx** is the page where you will be able to change it. But it is not recommanded to touch this file for editing. One of the best recommaned approach to achive what you want is [defined here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/22/customizing-moss-2007-my-sites-within-the-enterprise.aspx)

Comment: That master page doesn't have either of the tabs "My Site" or "My Profile" in there. From what I can see they come from some asp:menu / sitemap but it's this I'm having trouble locating.